# Display checkbox after select combo box

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I need some idea here.. i wanted to make search function using combo box. after user has selected certain value from the combo box...based on selected value checkbox will appears...

example ...

[combo box] -> select 1.user
                      2.item
                      3.tag

when user select "user"

checkbox as follow will appears

checkbox- update user    checkbox-delete user

and so forth... this to filter more.. and make user easy to find/view what they want from their search...

if you have other idea..instead of using combo box and check box.. please let me know..

thankssssssss :)

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried already?

Comment: Attach a `.change()` event to the `<select>` using jQ, and in that event handler create the checkboxes and add them to the DOM. Have a go at it yourself and come back when you have some code to debug, we are not here to write your code for you.

Comment: You can put them in separated divs with unique ids, and do a javascript hide/show function onclick

Comment: im not asking you to write code here.. just ive tried to look around but seems not found the right one..maybe the way i search..

Comment: i ve tried.. only display select box..take data from database.. but i didnt try yet to display checkbox after value from combo box selected.. because i dont know

Comment: by the way ..thanks for the answers.. im trying now..

Comment: if i use javascript function.. on stand alone page its working .. but when i try on my project page.. its not workign.. on my project page.. i use div for element in tabs..

Comment: <script>
    $("select").change(function () {
          var str = "";
          $("select option:selected").each(function () {
                str += $(this).text() + " ";
              });
          $("div").text(str);
        })
        .change();
</script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your select list an ID.

Using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#mySelect").change(function(){
    var selectValue = $("#mySelect").val();
    switch(selectValue){
      case "someValue":
        var checkbox = '<input type="checkbox" name="something" value="something" />'
        $("#someDiv").append(checkbox);
        break;
      case "someOtherValue":
        var checkbox = '<input type="checkbox" name="something" value="something" />'
        $("#someDiv").append(checkbox);
        break;
    }
  });
});
```

And so on. Hopefully, you get the idea.

Comment: penco.. can i know which jQuery library do you use? jQuery.tools.min.js or other? whenever i use other library.? i doesnt work on mine.

Comment: echo '<select name="SearchCriteria"  id="SearchCriteria" style="font:12px Verdana ; width:150px;" >';         
  echo '<option value="">Select Search</option>';
   
   for ($i =0; $i<$rowcount; $i++)  
  {  

   $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql); 
       echo 
       '<option ';
         $value = $row['p_on'];          
   echo 'value="' . $value . '">' . $value .'</option>';
  
  }
           
  echo '</select>';

Comment: <script>
 document.ready(function(){
   $("SearchCriteria").change(function(){
     var selectValue = $("SearchCriteria").val();
     switch(selectValue){
       case "user":
        var checkbox = '<input type="checkbox" name="something" value="something" />'
        $("div").append(checkbox);
        break;
        case "someOtherValue":
        var checkbox = '<input type="checkbox" name="something" value="something" />'
        $("div").append(checkbox);
        break;
     }
   });
 });

Comment: Not sure why my answer isn't "accepted" when it basically is exactly what you used, except you replaced my filler values with actual names.

Comment: Thanks. Glad I could help. Btw my original post probably gave you issue because I forgot to put $() around document.ready. It should have been $(document).ready

Answer (score 0):

finally i managed to do... 
thanks all for your help ... 
this is what i did

select statement

```
echo '<select name="SearchCriteria"  id="SearchCriteria" style="font:12px Verdana ; width:150px;" >';                             
    echo '<option value="">Select Search</option>';

     for ($i =0; $i<$rowcount; $i++)  
    {  

     $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql); 
     echo 
     '<option ';
     $value = $row['p_on'];                                     
     echo 'value="' . $value . '">' . $value .'</option>';

    }

    echo '</select>';
```

div and script below the select statement

```
<div id="Checkbox"></div>

        <script>

 $("select").change(function(){
    var selectValue = $("select").val();
    switch(selectValue){
    case "user":
    var checkbox = '<input type="checkbox" name="something" value="something" />'
    $("#Checkbox").append(checkbox);
    break;
     case "tag":
    var checkbox = '<input type="checkbox" name="something" value="something" />'
    $("#Checkbox").append(checkbox);
    break;
    }
 });

</script>
```

Comment: Congrats on the fix! When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others may learn from your success. Cheers~